# Postgres: transform json object into array of key-value pairs

Tags: json, postgresql

With this select:

```
SELECT '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}'::jsonb
```

can we transform the result object into the following array of objects keeping their keys and values respectively?

```
[{"key1": "value1"}, {"key2": "value2"}]
```

In my case, I have many-2-many relationship of tags and operations, and the following query with aggregation of tags into json object for each operation:

```
SELECT ot.operation_id, json_object_agg(t.name, t.value) AS tagsjson 
FROM tag t 
INNER JOIN operation_tag ot ON t.tag_id = ot.tag_id 
GROUP BY ot.operation_id
```

This works fine except format of the result: I need array of tags `[{name : value},...]` instead of whole object containing tags as it's properties:

[image]

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: @stickybit there is no error or unexpected, I just ask is there a function (or a technique) to do this, maybe somebody knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are in a situation like the following:

your source table contains `id`, `keys` and `values` like the below

```
create table test_k_v (id int, k varchar, v varchar);

insert into test_k_v values (1, 'key1', 'value1');
insert into test_k_v values (1, 'key2', 'value2');
insert into test_k_v values (2, 'key3', 'value3');
insert into test_k_v values (2, 'key4', 'value4');
insert into test_k_v values (2, 'key5', 'value5');
```

which results in

```
defaultdb=> select * from test_k_v;
 id |  k   |   v    
----+------+--------
  1 | key1 | value1
  1 | key2 | value2
  2 | key3 | value3
  2 | key4 | value4
  2 | key5 | value5
(5 rows)
```

If so, you can create an array with all the tags with the following query:

```
select id, array_agg(json_build_object(k, v)) agg_res 
from  test_k_v
group by id;
```

result

```
 id |                                     agg_res                                     
----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | {"{\"key3\" : \"value3\"}","{\"key4\" : \"value4\"}","{\"key5\" : \"value5\"}"}
  1 | {"{\"key1\" : \"value1\"}","{\"key2\" : \"value2\"}"}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just `jsonb_agg` instead of `array_agg` in my case to have outer array, not object. Bravo!